# addEventListener() onchange on input field based on changes from Server

Tags: javascript, html

I have a button and I have an input1 field in HTML file. When the button clicked, server returns a value incremented by one and displayed in input1 field.

In javascript file: For time performance test: I want to save time (milliseconds) when the button clicked, and I want to save time when incremented value returns from server in the input1 field.

Is there some kind EventListener in JS that detects value change made by server in an input field?

I have tried addEventListener but does not work, as you know, it only detects changes made by user. Please point me in the right direction.

```
function myFunction() {
    var mss = performance.now();
    document.getElementById("time").innerHTML="Click Time in milliseconds: "+mss;

    document.input1.addEventListener("change", getTime(mss),false); 
}

function getTime(e){
    var rt = performance.now();
    var ms = e;
    var diff= rt-ms;
    document.getElementById("returnTime").innerHTML="Return time in milliseconds:"+ ms;
    document.getElementById("timeDiff").innerHTML="Time Difference in milliseconds:"+ diff;
}
```

Comment: Any particular reason you're not just calling `getTime(mss)` directly at the bottom of `myFunction()`, in addition to the `onchange` listener?

Comment: "I want to save time when incremented value returns from server" — What server? Why are you expecting this server to return anything? How is the server supposed to change the input (which is part of the DOM that exists on the client)?

Comment: @JonUleis
I have tried that. It just reacts on my button click immediately, and returns almost same action time, it does not give me the time of input1 value change. 
What I want it to do is, when I click on the button, click time should return (mss), and then it should wait for value change in input1, and when input1 changes its value, then it should return rt time.
The click on the button sends a call to the server, the server increments a variable and sends it back with 1 sec delay. The incremented value then displayed in input1. I need the time of the change of the input1 value.

Comment: @Quentin It is OPC server. Because in this application it is the server which is responsible for the increment of a variable. The server return the value, then I display it in the input1 by this line: `document.input1 = document.getElementById("content_0_NumericInput1").childNode‌​s`

Answer (score 3):

You are calling the function getTime this line, instead of in the event listener.

`document.input1.addEventListener("change", getTime(mss),false);`

I believe what you want to do instead is:

`document.input1.addEventListener("change", getTime.bind(null, mss),false);`

Comment: It does not work. getTime() still returns the time of click, and not the time of input1 value change. For the sake of testing, from the time button is clicked till input1 changes it's value, I have put a delay of 1 sec, But eventlistener still returns me the time of click.